# After upgrading to Mojave lpass-cli fails to execute properly?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, mojave

After upgrading from High Sierra to Mojave I started encountering the following error:

```
$ lpass login <username>
lpass(1773,0x10e0ec5c0) malloc: *** error for object 0xec83485354415541: pointer being freed was not allocated
lpass(1773,0x10e0ec5c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue appears to be with `lpass` itself, after upgrading to Mojave. The issue was reported in various forms on the LastPass Github project page for `lastpass-cli`. Specifically this issue: [Segfaults on macOS Mojave Beta #427](https://github.com/lastpass/lastpass-cli/issues/427).

The solution is pretty straightforward. Simply upgrading `lastpass-cli` via `brew` like so:

```
$ brew upgrade lastpass-cli
```

Resulting in this version being installed which fixes the `malloc` issue mentioned.

```
$ brew info lastpass-cli
lastpass-cli: stable 1.3.3 (bottled), HEAD
LastPass command-line interface tool
https://github.com/lastpass/lastpass-cli
/usr/local/Cellar/lastpass-cli/1.3.3 (10 files, 216.6KB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2019-04-15 at 15:15:05
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/lastpass-cli.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: asciidoc ✘, cmake ✘, docbook-xsl ✔, pkg-config ✔
Required: curl ✔, openssl ✔, pinentry ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

zsh completions have been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> Analytics
install: 2,555 (30 days), 5,077 (90 days), 18,589 (365 days)
install_on_request: 2,378 (30 days), 4,832 (90 days), 17,108 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)
```

Version details from CLI:

```
$ lpass --version
LastPass CLI v1.3.3.GIT
```